# Does Jackson Deserialization into a JsonNode Guarantee Property Ordering?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

For example, if I deserialize the following JSON into a JsonNode:

```
{
   "property1": 1,
   "property2": 2,
   "property3": 3
}
```

and then traverse the elements with [JsonNode#fields](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()), is there any guarantee that the iterator will return the properties in the order they were defined (i.e. property1, property2, property3)?

Intuitively I would assume the answer is no, because the JSON spec defines objects as "an unordered set of name/value pairs". HOWEVER, [JSON RFC (RFC 7159)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) says this:

> JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or
> not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling
> software.

And I haven't been able to find any information about how Jackson handles this.

Answer (score 3):

looking at the [source code of Jackson's `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.5.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.java?av=f) (version 2.5.0, you can search on the site for a different one), the map which holds the object's children is of type [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) where the documentation says

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked
>   list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in
>   which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

Comment: This is a start but doesn't really answer the question. With this knowledge I guess my question then becomes, "Does Jackson guarentee in-order insertion of properties into its LinkedHashMap when deserializing?"

Comment: I don't see why Jackson dev would choose such an implementation for any other reason

Comment: While it wouldn't make any sense to use a `LinkedHashMap` and not implement strict property ordering, having it explicitly guaranteed by Jackson would be nice. When you have a key business algorithm depending on field order, knowing that Jackson asserts and maintains ordering is more solid justification than a hunch and empirical evidence of the *current* implementation.